# Filtering By More Than One Attribute in JQuery

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I am just wondering whether that is a correct syntax in JQuery :

```
var elements = $("#contact-area input[type=text,value=something] ").get();
```

What I mean is how to write specify more than one parameter to and filter apart from this use :

```
$("#contact-area (input[type=text],input[value=something])").get();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put each attribute in it's own `[]` (no spaces in between attributes).

```
var elements = $("#contact-area input[type=text][value=something] ").get();
```

or

```
var elements = $("#contact-area input:text[value=something] ").get();
```

Comment: Updated link: [Multiple Attribute Selector \[name="value"\]\[name2="value2"\]](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/)